# _IENavigate returning error -1 and setting @error flag to 0 but @error should never be 0 according to AutoIt docs

Tags: windows, autoit

I've got an AutoIt script that goes to a website, logs in, and navigates to another page. But _IENavigate is throwing an error that isn't in [the documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IENavigate.htm) . The output to the following code is: "Here is what the flag is: -1 and the error flag is: 0"

But you'll see in the documentation that only error codes 1-9 exist, there is no flag for @error = 0...

I do notice that the browser does navigate to the second page but when I try getting all the  tags on the page, it doesn't find them. Please help! :)

```
Local $oIE = _IE

Create("http://www.example.com/")

_IELoadWait($oIE)

Local $j_username = _IEGetObjByName($oIE, "username")

_IEFormElementSetValue($j_username, $sUser)

Local $j_password = _IEGetObjByName($oIE, "password")

_IEFormElementSetValue($j_password, $sPass)

Local $login_submit = _IEGetObjByName($oIE, "button")

_IEAction($login_submit, "click")

_IELoadWait($oIE)

$iFlag = _IENavigate($oIE, "http://www.example.com/page2", 1)

ConsoleWrite( "Here is what the flag is: " & $iFlag & " and the error flag is: " & @error & @CRLF)

_IELoadWait($oIE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the documentation says:

```
This function always returns a value of -1. This is because the navigate method has no useful return value and therefore nothing can be implied from it.
```

It's a feature, not a bug. :)